# Wie kam »etwas ist alle« zur Bedeutung »etwas ist aufgebraucht«?

Tags: meaning, etymology

Wenn man bei uns in Österreich feststellt, dass kein Brot, keine Milch, kein Klopapier usw. mehr da ist, sagt man:

> Das Brot ist aus.
>   Die Milch ist aus.
>   Das Klopapier ist aus.
>   usw.

In Deutschland (vor allem weiter im Norden) scheint aber diese Formulierung gebräuchlicher zu sein:

> Das Brot ist alle.
>   Die Milch ist alle.
>   Das Klopapier ist alle.
>   usw.

Wie alle Germanismen breitet sich auch die Floskel *»etwas ist alle«* (bei der *»alle«* nicht wie sonst üblich als Indefinitpronomen, sondern als Adverb verwendet wird) seit einigen Jahrzehnten auch in Österreich aus und wird hierzulande kaum noch als deutschländisch oder sonst wie ungewöhnlich empfunden. Meiner persönlichen Einschätzung nach sagt schon rund ein Viertel bis zu einem Drittel aller Österreicher *»etwas ist alle«* (vor allem jüngere Sprecher).

Mir ist aber nach wie vor unklar, wie es dazu kam, dass *»etwas ist alle«* zur Bedeutung *»etwas ist aufgebraucht«* kam.

---

Die Floskel *»etwas ist aus«* für Zeiträume, die ein deutlich erkennbares Ende haben, halte ich für relativ alt:

> Die Ferien sind aus.
>   Der Unterricht ist aus.
>   Die Messe ist aus.
>   Der Sommer ist aus.

Dass sich diese zeitraumgebundene Bedeutung auf das Vorhandensein von Verbrauchsgütern übertragen hat (die ja auch nur während eines bestimmten Zeitraums verfügbar sind), scheint mir auf der Hand zu liegen, zumal das Wort *»aus«* auch in der ursprünglichen Verwendungsart bereits ein Adverb ist, das Wort also keinen Wortartwechsel durchmachen musste.

Aber im Fall von *»etwas ist alle«* kann ich mir nicht einmal ansatzweise erklären, wie das Indefinitpronomen *»alle«* zu einem Adverb mit der Bedeutung *»nicht mehr vorhanden«* geworden ist.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Blatz behauptet in seiner [Neuhochdeutschen Grammatik](https://archive.org/details/neuhochdeutscheg02blatuoft/page/294), es läge eine Ellipse zugrunde, ohne das näher auszuführen. Ich vermute, er meint,

> Sind eure Blumen alle? *(Grillparzer)*

sei aus

> Sind eure Blumen alle {verbraucht, weg}?

entstanden. (Das Beispiel ist insofern interessant, als Grillparzer Österreicher war.)

So könnte man aber allenfalls die Entstehung einer neuen Bedeutung erklären, da ein Beispiel wie

> Und damit ists noch nicht alle! *(Schiller)*

nicht auf eine Ellipse zurückgeführt werden kann.

Das [Deutsche Wörterbuch](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemma=all) wendet sich (unter II., 6.) gegen die Erklärung mittels Ellipse, da man so *alle machen* für *töten* nicht erklären könne. Sie verweisen auf eine parallele Doppeldeutigkeit bei *fertig* (*bereit* gegenüber *erschöpft*) und vermuten trotz fehlender Belege aus mhd. und ahd. Zeit einen germanischen Ursprung. Aus dem Altnordischen wird angeführt: *hann varð þar allr*, er starb dort.

Die Grimmsche Deutung erscheint mir plausibler: Es liegt eine alte Doppeldeutigkeit vor.  Das Pronomen oder Artikelwort hat die Bedeutung *ganz, vollständig* (auch in Distanzstellung):

> Alle Kinder bekommen ein Geschenk.
>   Die Kinder bekommen alle ein Geschenk.

Dieses *all-* kommt selbstverständlich mit allen Verben vor. Das prädikative *alle* hat die Bedeutung *zu Ende, erschöpft* und tritt nur mit *sein, werden, machen* auf. Wenn eine Person oder ein Dialekt dieses zweite *alle* vergißt, dann versucht man, es wie Blatz vom ersten abzuleiten, und scheitert.

Das DWB hat ein Beispiel, in dem beide Wörter gemeinsam auftreten:

> es ist alles all, *alles ist aus*

In [diesem Wörterbuch](https://reader.digitale-sammlungen.de/de/fs1/object/display/bsb10692286_00145.html?zoom=1.0) findet man Belege aus Luthers Schriften. Die Bedeutung *tot* ist hier sehr häufig. Darunter findet sich noch ein Beispiel mit beiden Wörtern:

> Allis Allmachens hab ich ein End gesehen.

Eine parallele Bedeutungsverschiebung von *bereit, fertig* zu *aufgebraucht, zu Ende* findet sich laut [DWB](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemma=gar), [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/gar_fertig_weich) und [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/gar) bei *gar* im süddeutschen Raum.

> Es [das Geld] war bald gar. (DWDS)

Comment: Wieso "Parallele Bedeutungsverschiebung"? Angesichts Alemanen ~ Germanen, sowie gewisser Lautwandel vereinzelt nachweisbar ist, dürfte einundaselbe Wort sein. Vgl. *gr-own up*, *ad-ult*, bzw. *gar nichts, janüscht, jeh*, bitte, und halt dich nicht an dem verkappten Geschwurbel verklemmter Antisemiten des vorvorigen Jahrhunderts fest. *Ad ultimo*, na los, tu es, sonst downvote.

Answer (score 5):

> *"Mir ist aber nach wie vor unklar, wie es dazu kam, dass »etwas ist
> alle« zur Bedeutung »etwas ist aufgebraucht« kam." - "Aber im Fall von
> »etwas ist alle« kann ich mir nicht einmal ansatzweise erklären, wie
> das Indefinitpronomen »alle« zu einem Adverb mit der Bedeutung »nicht
> mehr vorhanden« geworden ist."*

Vielleicht hilft ja Kluge, der eine Vermutung äußert:

> "Die regionale Bedeutung 'leer, ausgegangen'  (**alle werden** usw. < 16.
> Jh., vor allem omd.) beruht wohl auf einem Konstruktionswechsel oder
> einer Ellipse: Wenn z.B. die Kartoffeln im Keller **alle** verbraucht
> sind, dann sind sie **alle**."

Adelung hat sich auf die Deskription beschränkt:

> All. Aller, alle, alles, ein Wort, welches in den meisten Fällen den
> Begriff der Allgemeinheit ausdrucket, und in dreyerley Gestalt üblich
> ist.
>
> I. * Als ein Umstandswort,    welches dessen ursprüngliche
> Gestalt ist, der Zahl, Menge und innern Stärke nach erschöpft. Der
> Wein ist schon all, es ist kein Wein mehr da, er ist verbraucht. Sein
> Vermögen all machen, erschöpfen, verzehren. Es wird bald alles all
> seyn. Bis daß eure Leiber all werden in der Wüsten, 4. Mos. 14, 33.
> Die Missethat der Amoriter ist noch nicht alle, 1. Mos. 15, 16. Das
> größte Vergnügen wird alle, wenn die Frau keine Wirthinn ist, Gell.

Woraus wir lernen, dass bereits Luther *all* für *aufgebraucht* im weitesten Sinn benutzt - nicht *aus*. Wie er vor etwa 500 Jahren dazu kam?

Wenn wir die einleitende Erläuterung Adelungs akzeptieren, is *all* die "ursprüngliche Gestalt" des Worts und bedeutet, schon immer: "der Zahl, Menge und innern Stärke nach erschöpft". Womit sich dann deine Frage "Wie kam's denn dazu?" also erst gar nicht stellt.

**edit; @ Hubert S.**

*"Aus den bisherigen Antworten habe ich gelernt, dass die Bedeutung »aufgebraucht = alle« offensichtlich einen niederdeutschen Ursprung hat"*

Versuch's doch mal mit *close reading*. Kluge schreibt, dass *alle* in der Bedeutung 'leer, ausgegangen' "...vor allem omd." ist. Noch mal: **o-m-d**. Adelung verweist auf Luther, der bekanntermaßen wo lebte? Und folglich was sprach und schrieb? Eben: weder nieder- noch oberdeutsch.  Luthers Sprache ist zu einem nicht unbeträchtlichen Teil der Standard für (Neu-)Hochdeutsch geworden, der noch immer gilt. Wenn also überhaupt etwas zu fragen ist, dann, wie es zu Deviationen kommt à la * *"Die Ferien sind aus. / Der Sommer ist aus"*, was in der standardsprachlichen
Form * *Die Ferien sind alle. / Der Sommer ist alle.* schlichtweg nicht vorkommen kann. Noch mal: Nicht der Standard ist zu hinterfragen, sondern die Deviation.

Comment: *»Womit sich dann deine Frage "Wie kam's denn dazu?" also erst gar nicht stellt.«* Das sehe ich anders. Aus den bisherigen Antworten habe ich gelernt, dass die Bedeutung *»aufgebraucht = alle«* offensichtlich einen niederdeutschen Ursprung hat, während *»aufgebraucht = aus«* aus dem oberdeutschen Sprachraum zu stammen scheint. Die Bedeutung *»zu Ende = aus«*, die meiner Meinung nach mit *»aufgebraucht = aus«* verwandt ist (siehe zweite Hälfte meiner Frage), dürfte daher wahrscheinlich auch eher oberdeutsche Wurzeln haben. ...

Comment: ... Im Süden sagt man *»die Pause ist aus«* und *»die Milch ist aus«.* Im Norden sagt man - soweit mir das bekannt ist - aber nur *»Die Milch ist alle«.* Ich glaube nicht, dass jemand den Satz *»die Pause ist alle«* sagen würde. Und angesichts dessen halte ich es schon für legitim zu fragen, wie es dazu kam.

Comment: "Die Kartoffeln sind verbraucht" impliziert bereits, dass alle Kartoffeln nicht mehr da sind - "alle verbraucht" ist eine unnötige Verdopplung. "Die Kartoffeln sind alle mehligkochend" dagegen zeigt, dass auf das "verbraucht" nicht verzichtet werden kann, außer "alle" hätte zwei unterschiedliche Bedeutungen.

Answer (score 2):

Meines Wissens (wurde mal in der Schule mehr oder weniger beiläufig erwähnt) stammt das vom französischen "allé", was eben (aus)gegangen bedeutet. Das wurde als eines von mehreren Beispielen genannt, welche französischen Begriffe, die von den Hugenotten nach Preußen mitgebracht wurden, in die hiesige Sprache eingeflossen sind (und deren Ursprung als Fremdwort - auch aufgrund von Verballhornung - nicht mehr offensichtlich ist).

Comment: Leider kann das nicht stimmen, denn damit kann man die [gleichbedeutende Form *all*](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&lemma=all) nicht erklären.

Comment: Es bedürfte nur einer Erklärung für den Verlust der Endung. Da Französisch nicht erst von den Hugenotten erfunden wurde, steht die Möglichkeit einer älteren Entlehnung offen.

Comment: @Takkat erzähl mir nicht was ich kann und was nicht. Du kannst mit "Mann" ebensowenig die Form "ma" erklären, die sich doch recht einfach aus Liason ergibt, was dich bisher nie daran gehindert hätte, den Vergleich trotzdem zu siehen. Mimimimose

Comment: All Erdings verwechselt Folker Landgrav das Bezugswort der Anekdote doch mit *Allee* "Straße, Weg". Oder die Lehrerin tat so.

Answer (score 2):

Es gibt noch andere Sprachen, die für "komplett, vollständig" und "zu Ende" das gleiche Wort verwenden. Zum Beispiel Persisch tamām (تمام), vielleicht auch arabisch. Auch vietnamesisch hết rồi (wörtlich *schon alle*) bedeutet dasselbe. Die dahinterstehenden Konzepte sind ja auch halbwegs miteinander kompatibel, zum Beispiel wenn man an Zeiträume denkt.

Comment: Arabisch *kala* bedeuted *nichts*, "void". Hmmm

Comment: Das  ت in تمام. Ich muss aber meinen vorigen Kommentar korrigieren:  ت kommt im Persischen auch in Nicht-Fremdwörtern sehr häufig vor, anders als ط. Das arabische Pendant dazu (mit viel engerer Bedeutung?) siehe z. B. https://de.langenscheidt.com/arabisch-deutsch/تمام

Comment: Auch im Englischen. [Merriam-Webster zu _all_:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/all) "(7) dialect : used up : entirely consumed —used especially of food and drink"

Comment: Im Japanischen gibt es ganz ähnliche Konzepte: Aus Fragewörtern wie 「いつ」("itsu", "wann?") oder 「誰」("dare", "wer?") kann man mit der Endung 「〜も」("-mo") Begriffe für alle oder keine Instanz machen. Das heißt, 「いつも」 steht mit einem affirmativen Verb für "immer", mit einem negierten Verb für "nie". Analog 「誰も」 mit einem affirmativen Verb für "jeder", mit einem negierten Verb für "niemand".

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice background on: *Das ist schon alle alle.*
Diese Redensart kommt aus Berlin, das heute noch die meisten Worte aus dem Französischen hat. Die meisten Hugenotten kamen nach Berlin und brachten ihre großen, handwerklichen Fähigkeiten mit. Auf der Friedrichstraße an der Brücke saßen  Frauen mit ihren wunderbar gestickten Taschentüchern. Sie waren oft ausverkauft und die Frauen sagten nur *alle alle* (bitte entschuldigt die Schreibweise) mit der Bedeutung *gegangen gegangen*.

Die Berliner haben die Bedeutung sofort begriffen, haben nur die Betonung völlig verändert. Es ist schon sehr lustig, wie manche Worte oder Aussprachen aus einer anderen Sprache übernommen werden. Die Hugenotten konnten das deutsche *au* nicht aussprechen und haben daraus ihr *o* gemacht. Noch heute hört man in Berlin: *Det kof ick nich.*

Comment: Das klingt nicht sehr glaubwürdig. Kannst du das mit irgendwelchen Fakten belegen? Auf mich wirkt diese Antwort, als wäre sie frei erfunden.

Comment: Kopenhagen ist mit der selben Wurzel verwandt wie kofen und zwar schon lange vor Hugenotten.

Answer (score -2):

Französisch *allé* /a.le/ heißt *ging*, bzw. *est aller* "ist gegangen*, vgl En. *gone (out)*, Ger. *ausgegangen* "weg". *weg* hat ja auch eine vermutlich nicht rein zufällige Homophonie mit *der Weg*.

Gehalten haben dürfte sich die eher abwegige Übernahme dann wegen dem witzigen reim *alle alle* "all gone". Die *Allee* dürfte damit vergleichbar sein.

Allerdings ist nicht geklärt, woher *aller* überhaupt kam. Spätes Vulgär Latein wird als Möglichkeit betrachtet.