# Bier ist alle (there is no more beer)

Tags: word-usage, etymology, meaning-in-context

Can someone please explain why? I have heard [this](https://context.reverso.net/translation/german-english/Bier+ist+alle) all my life, but don't know why we say it.

Obviously, there is a word missing ... `Bier ist alle XXX`, but what is XXX ?

There are some comments linking to a similar/duplicate question, ***BUT*** that is entirely in German and I would like to see an English language explanation.

Comment: See (in German) https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/48579/wie-kam-etwas-ist-alle-zur-bedeutung-etwas-ist-aufgebraucht

Comment: A good one (+1), and good that it points out that Austria uses `aus` in place of `alle - `Bier ist aus`. But I would like to see an English language explanation

Comment: That's the same question as linked by @DavidVogt :-) I would like to see an English language explanation

Comment: Reminder to the (potential) close voters: “Duplicates” in another language [_aren’t considered true duplicates_.](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/807/what-to-do-with-duplicate-questions-in-another-language)

Comment: It is true that same questions in different languages should not be considered duplicates per site rules. However, all the answers to the linked question are speculations, no one does know the correct answer.

Comment: Upvote; then you can post that here as an answer - in English :-)